# when i press enter key, checkbox displayed in <div> disappears

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code which I tried, it should work like this: Text written in text-box, should appear as check-box in div tag.

I used `onchange()` function.  It worked fine when I moved out of text box, but when I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, check-box appears for few seconds and disappears.  Nothing is displayed in div.

How to solve this problem? What really happens when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> while writing in text-box?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
            <p>
                <label for="textfield">Hello</label>
                <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" onChange="add_items(this.value)" />
            </p>
            <br>
            <div id="item"></div>
        </form>

        <script>
        k=""
        function add_items(m)
        {
            k=k+"<input type=checkbox name=menu[] id=menu[] value="+m+">"+m+"&nbsp;";
            document.getElementById("item").innerHTML=k
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onsubmit="return false;" will solve your issue

Answer (score 3):

You are submitting the form by pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Add `onsubmit="return false;"` to your `form` tag.

Comment: yeah.. okay! I am new to stackoverflow. i wasn't aware of it

Comment: i did as you told, worked fine in chrome and mozilla. but it wont work properly in internet explorer

Comment: Im sorry, but I dont care for IE. Try removing the form tag completely.